# Hoisting in Javascript example

Tags: javascript

In the following example, why does the second `f()` prints `2`.

I was thinking it would print `3` since the function prints in the same context where it is called.

```js
(function() {
  f();
  f = function() {
    console.log(2);
  }
}());

function f() {
  console.log(3);
}
f();
```

Comment: There is _only one_ `f` binding. The IIFE assigns a different value to that binding at the start, after the first `f()` call.

Comment: `f` is *reassigned*.

Comment: @VLAZ comment is key here.  `function f () { .. }` is different than `f = function() { ... }`

Comment: @VLAZ : Does the automatic function (function () { ...}}  at lines 1 gets defined at global context so that the function that prints "3" is overridden?

Comment: This is because function definitions are being loaded when script loads, after that they are being run ... so generally second definition "`function f()`" is first in order, then after loading the whole script and it's variables and definitions, the "`(function () ...`" is being run, overwriting the first definition. Why? Without that you wouldn't be able to use functions that are being defined later in code. And you are.

Comment: @User1897891 doesn't matter *where* it's defined. It reassigns the same `f` that's used outside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the execution order.

1. function f() hoisted
2. IIFE executes and creates a global object called f

The second step overshadows the hoisted function due to its name and due to the fact that is being declared as a global variable

If you put var or let before the function expression Inside the IIFE and move the function call below the  expression, the second call would have printed 3.

```js
(function() {


  var f = function() {
    console.log(2);
  }
  
  f();
}());

function f() {
  console.log(3);
}
f();
```

Comment: "*IIFE executes and creates a global variable called f*" it doesn't? It changes the existing global variable called `f`.

Comment: "*If you put var or let before the function expression Inside the IIFE, the second call would have printed 3.*" technically no, it wouldn't do that, because the code would throw an error at the first `f()` and thus won't execute the rest.

Comment: Thanks. But it will not throw an error - because the hoisted function is already available in the global scope. However, I edited my answer to be clearer.

Comment: Also, the function expression will create a separate object in the heap. It's reference overshadows the reference of the function declaration. Now the latter can be taken in off by the garbage collector.

Comment: "*it will not throw an error*" it **does**. [`var` is hoisted in the IIFE, so `f()` will attempt too execute `undefined`](https://jsbin.com/xojevir/1/edit?js,console), while [`let` will produce a temporal dead zone error](https://jsbin.com/losamoj/edit?js,console) but the core cause is the same. That's what happens if you add a `var` or a `let` in the IIFE.

Comment: "*Also, the function expression will create a separate object in the heap.*" creates a new object but will not create a new global variable `f`. There is a single global variable created by the hoisted function declaration. The IIFE reassigns that value of the variable, doesn't create another variable.

Comment: Thanks, You are correct. The var f  is hoisted and it becomes undefined first., Answer edited.  On the other point,, the name "f" is taken at the beginning of the script. So, of course, the var is there. But the function expression creates a  new object and there is no replacement there.  I edited the word "variable" in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

When `function f()` is hoisted, but `f = function()` is not hoisted, this results in following order:

```js
// hoisted
function f()
{
  console.log(3);
}

(function () {
    f(); // uses definition with 3
    // overwrites f
    f = function()
    {
      console.log(2);
    }
}());

f(); // uses overwritten f with 2
```